# Prove following inequality

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Prove that $(\frac{2a}{b+c})^\frac{2}{3}+(\frac{2b}{a+c})^\frac{2}{3}+(\frac{2c}{a+b})^\frac{2}{3} ≥ 3$
What I tried was to use AM-GM for the left side of this inequality, what I got was
$3(\frac{8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)})^\frac{2}{9}≥ 3$ and $(\frac{8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)})^\frac{2}{9}≥ 1$ or just $\frac{8abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}≥ 1$, but this isn't true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By AM-GM
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{2a}{b+c}\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{\left(\frac{b+c}{2a}\right)^2\cdot1}}\geq\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{\frac{\frac{b+c}{2a}+\frac{b+c}{2a}+1}{3}}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{3a}{a+b+c}=3.$$

Comment: Creative AM-GM! +1

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

WLOG you may set $a+b+c=3$ and show instead that for $x\in[0,3]$,
$$\left(\frac{2x}{3-x}\right)^{2/3}\geqslant x$$

But this is equivalent to the obvious $x^2(4-x)(x-1)^2\geqslant0$.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid question to ask, but what if x is for example 3.5? Then your inequality is not quite correct?

Comment: @Severus156 $x\in [0,3]$, as once you’ve scaled to $a+b+c=3$, none among $a,b,c$ can exceed $3$…

Comment: Nice solution! +1.

Comment: Oh, thank you for explanation @Macavity, nice solution indeed:)